# Get the dynamic alloccated port of a IPEndPoint

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, endpoint

How is it possible to get the dynamically assigned port of a IPEndPoint, when you create it with 0 as port:

```
var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostAddresses(localhost).FirstOrDefault(), 0);
```

If I look at the endpoint.Port, it is 0 (any), even tho the underlaying Socket must have an designated port already?

Comment: You can get all the infos in : tcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint or tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint and tcpListener.LocalEndPoint

Comment: Since I use the endpoint for SIP traffic, I need to support both UDP and TCP, so in this case I need to either use udpclient or a tcpclient. I guess a udpclient got same possibilities? If it isn't possible at all to get the dynamic port from the IPEndPoint, this could be a solution.

Comment: Yes, for both udp and tcp, you can use Socket class. This "RemoteEndPoint" and "LocalEndPoint" are from Socket class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI:
[Socket.RemoteEndPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Socket.LocalEndPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.localendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx)